# error 550001 in paypal adaptive chained payment api

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am getting below response in PayPal Adaptive Payments API. I am not sure what does it means? Please help me with it.

```
Array
(
    [responseEnvelope.timestamp] => 2014-01-27T01:07:55.101-08:00
    [responseEnvelope.ack] => Failure
    [responseEnvelope.correlationId] => 34213dd3fb305
    [responseEnvelope.build] => 7935900
    [error(0).errorId] => 550001
    [error(0).domain] => PLATFORM
    [error(0).subdomain] => Application
    [error(0).severity] => Error
    [error(0).category] => Application
    [error(0).message] => User is not allowed to perform this action
    [error(0).parameter(0)] => Fees Payer
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out? I am having the same issue, and my app is supposed to be 100% approved for chained payments.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it means exactly what it says.  You don't have permissions to make the call based on certain criteria.

Do you have a valid, live App ID?  If so, has it been fully approved to do everything you're trying to do?  Are you making implicit or explicit authenticated payments?  You may need to have your end users go through Permissions or setup a Preapproval profile in order to make payments on their behalf.